# android source?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I was looking to download “android emulator source code” and can’t seem to find it anywhere. Can you please tell me where I can download it, and what language does the “android emulator source code” written in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) are instructions for getting set up with Android, setting up your build environment, and building (including building the Emulator).

Comment: As far as I can tell, [this](https://github.com/android/platform_external_qemu/tree/6370eaba73e2925de6b331c93ce10acc10ac88f9) is the main Github mirror for the emulator source code. You should be able to browse the source files and answer your questions from there. Looks like lots of it's in C.

Answer (score 1):

As found on [this](http://discuz-android.blogspot.com/2008/01/about-google-android-emulator.html) site, you can download the **Android Emulator** source code [here](http://android.googlecode.com/files/android-emulator-m3-rc37.tar.bz2).